# TinyMCE - automatically insert additional attributes when copying/pasting content?

Tags: html, django, tinymce

Is there a way to configure TinyMCE to automatically insert additional attribues when copying and pasting content into a textarea?

In my case, I have a textarea that I copy/paste content with text and images. When images are inserted, I would like to automatically mark the img tags as having a specific CSS class (for ensuring they are fluid).

I'm using Django TinyMCE is that makes any difference. Has anyone succeeded in achieving this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TinyMCE `Paste` plugin has the ability for you to pre or post process the content during the paste process.

I would recommend using the `postprocess` API as this allows the `Paste` plugin to do its cleanup first.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_postprocess

For example you could do something like this in your TinyMCE init (not that this is what you want to do I just had this example handy from a project):

```
paste_postprocess: function(editor, fragment) {
    var allElements = fragment.node.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (i = 0; i < allElements.length; ++i) {
      console.log('initial font family: ', allElements[i].style.fontFamily);

      var st = allElements[i].style;
      stCleaned = st.fontFamily.replace("sans-serif", "").replace("Calibri", "Arial");
      st.fontFamily = stCleaned; // Indirectly
  }
}
```

...then each time the `Paste` plugin gets run your code will get run after it and you can manipulate the pasted content as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.